# Manually log in user using Quarkus

Tags: java, quarkus

I'm transitioning for Spring to Quarkus and wanted to try to code a simple login/register backend. The registration part works perfectly, but I have no clue how I can manually log in the user. Using spring I just used to have an endpoint that received the username and the password:

```
public void login(HttpServletRequest req, String user, String pass) { 
    var authReq = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(user, pass);
    var auth = authManager.authenticate(authReq);

    var sc = SecurityContextHolder.getContext();
    sc.setAuthentication(auth);
    var session = req.getSession(true);
    session.setAttribute(SPRING_SECURITY_CONTEXT_KEY, sc);
}
```

But with Quarkus there doesn't seem to be a way to do that. What am I supposed to do? What I have so far:

```
new AuthenticationBuilder().addUsername(username).addPassword(password).build().digest(AuthenticationDigest.forRepository());
```

But I have no clue how to continue

Comment: I have explored a bit about Qaurkus but I fear that with each REST request Username and Password need to be passed. Though it won't show the login page once you login successfully. Following for answer

Comment: Is the form based authentication involved ? Please check https://quarkus.io/guides/security#authenticating-via-http,  https://quarkus.io/guides/security-properties.

Comment: Already checked, there's no implementation of login. I guess I'll just use jwt as I always do, seems strange there's no session-based auth though

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, there is no implementation of session-based authentication (SBA) in Quarkus. In the [official security documentation](https://quarkus.io/guides/security) of the framework there are no references to SBA.

Comment: Thanks, it makes sense. I guess I'll just use jwt